# Can't understand mutable objects in python

Tags: python

So I thought that lists were MUTABLE objects in python so they could be changed.

When I create a list:

```
list = [1, 2, 3]
print(id(list))
list = [4, 5, 6]
print(id(list))
```

I should get the same ID in both cases.. But I got different one. Why is that?

Comment: You made a new list instead of mutating the object. Please explain in excruciating detail why you expected to get the same id.

Comment: and using a keyword as a variable name is not good practice

Comment: @MadPhysicist I am new to python so am a little confused. In languages like C/Java we can tell when we are declaring a new object ( int x=10 ) and when we are changing it ( x=5 ). How can we tell that in python? Is a new object created every time I use assignment operator (=) ?

Comment: @darth_yoda. I've added a paragraph (second to last one) in my answer to address your concern. Assignment does not create new objects. Ever.

Comment: @Ashkay. There's a big difference between keyword (which is really forbidden) and builtin name which is not). List is a builtin, but a keyword. In the end it's a name like any other, and can be rebound freely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator `=` with just a name on the left hand side always assigns an object to the name. It does not do anything else.

The operation `=` with a name that has an index (something in brackets) calls `__setitem__` on the named object.

You are invoking the first behavior. You are creating a new list, discarding the old one, and assigning the new one to the name `list`.

To mutate the object instead of replacing, you'll want to invoke the second behavior:

```
lst[:] = [4, 5, 6]
```

This assigns the new values to the *elements* of the original list. Now the contents of the original list will change, but it will be the same object with the same id, as you expected.

In both cases, a new list object is created any time you put a comma-separated list in square brackets. `[1, 2, 3]` creates a list and so does `[4, 5, 6]`. The difference is in what you do with the second list. `lst = [4, 5, 6]` assigns it to the name `lst`, discarding any previous object that name may have been bound to. `lst[:] = [4, 5, 6]` is actually roughly equivalent to doing `lst.__setitem__(slice (None), [4, 5, 6])`. This copies the elements of the second list into the first, but doesn't alter any name bindings.

And don't call a variable `list`. It shadows a builtin function. There's nothing fundamentally to prevent you from doing this, it's just rebinding a new object to an existing name (like your original example). But then you'll want to use the `list` function, and join the hordes on Stack Overflow always asking why their builtins don't work.

Answer (score 0):

In the second line, you are just creating a new list object and assigning it to list.

```
list=[4,5,6] //creates a new list object and puts its reference in list
```

To show that list are mutable, you can try applying operations on this line:

```
list=[1,2,3]
```

Like:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> id(a)
2814816838216
>>> a[0] = 4
>>> a
[4, 2, 3]
>>> id(a)
2814816838216
```